# Is there a way to connect 2 local folders to 2 seperate github branches

Tags: github

The title pretty much explains it, i am working on a discord bot and so i can work on a development version of the bot and then put over the code to the main version without copy and pasting everything, i want to have 2 seperate branches (main and dev), so would there be a way for me to connect my main bot folder to one branch (which is the folder i originally added to the repository), then add the dev folder to a second branch, then merge the code whenever i want to send the new code to heroku.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have two copies of the repo, each on different branches? Or if you can have two directories in the repo, which are only visible in different branches?

Comment: 2 directories in the repo which are only visible in different branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your `.gitignore`. Gitignore is just another file, and so is tracked in your branches. If your directories you want to conditionally ignore on each branch are called `prod` and `dev` for example, on your `master` (or `main`) branch, you can add `/dev` to your gitignore, and on your `dev`  branch you can add `/prod` to your gitignore. Here's an example of the shell commands in case that's not clear:

```
# initializing and setting up on master branch
mkdir test-repo
cd test-repo
git init
echo '/dev' > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -am 'init'

# setting up dev branch
git checkout -b dev
echo '/prod/' > .gitignore
mkdir {dev,prod}
touch dev/foo
touch prod/foo
git add .
git commit -am 'dev branch'

# checking back out to master
git checkout -
git add .
git commit -am 'add prod files'

# see which files are on this branch
git ls-files
# checkout the previous branch (dev)
git checkout - 
# see which files are on this branch
git ls-files
```